# how hibernate intteract with multiple database in mysql?

Tags: hibernate

I have to use hibernate with MySQL. I am also using spring MVC. There is a form where there are ten fields which have to store in three different tables. two of them are inside the same database, whereas the third one is in another database. how I can store them? Normally I am using @modelattribute . How I can construct the entity classes? and databases connection. There is a jdbc.properties file where the name of the database is given . Please help.

Comment: If you are using Hibernate  there should be a hibernate config file ..
how does jdbc.properties file come ??

Comment: actually I am using hibernate with springMVC, which contains jdbc.properties file.

Comment: Edited my answer for spring MVC.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar problem posted on [hibernate-forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=953983).

So the solution is basically creating two hibernate.cfg.xml files for the two databases. Then create two session factories. There wont be drastic changes in entities classes, but you would need to call two different save(), through session object of both session factories programatically.

If there are many complex mapping in your schema you better go for [hibernate shards](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/shards.html). here is a [similar reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100985/use-two-databases-concurrently-in-hibernate?rq=1)

**EDIT:**

Since your are using *spring MVC*, you need to specify two jdbc configurations in jdbc properties file and create two `datasource beans` in *applicationContext.xml, spring-servlet.xml* wherever you have created beans. Create corresponding `session factory` beans for the two DataSource and use them programatically to call your save() on the two database.

It should work :)